# Un-overwrite a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts

I made UserScripts, and am now stuck.

Inside of my HTML there is a script tag, and inside the script tag there is the following:

```
<script>
   setTimeout = function(){}
</script>
```

There is no way to use the function, its useless.

How can I solve this?

I was thinking using a way to set the function like `main = setTimeout()` and I can reset it after the script is loaded. Back to like `setTimeout = main`.

I am also trying to stay (mostly) undetected unlike running all of the code in a different environment like an iframe. I know you can just use `setInterval` and then break the loop, but this is just an example.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its formatting, spelling, and grammar are beyond what members of the stack overflow community should be expected to fix.

Comment: Can I ask **why** you are doing this. You said something about needing to do this instead of `setInterval` but that does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Run your userscript before the page has a chance to overwrite it. Use `// @run-at document-start` in the metadata block (combined with instant script injection in the Advanced section of Tampermonkey's config), and then you could do, in your userscript:

```
const origSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
// proceed with your script, referencing origSetTimeout
```

which will continue to work even after the page loads and has overwritten the original `setTimeout`. (While you could reassign `window.setTimeout` back to the original one later, that would be detectable - if that's really a concern.)

The variables declared in the userscript, even at the top level, will not leak out into the page scope, so don't worry about `origSetTimeout` being exposed - though other actions done in the userscript could be detected.